# Stop occasional Thunderbird sound notifications for junk emails

Tags: email, thunderbird, notifications, spam-prevention

Sometimes, but not always, a new email notification sound plays when junk mail is received.

So far it is only for a Hotmail account. It is possible that some junk emails first go to the inbox and are almost immediately flagged as junk and moved to the junk folder on the server.

Nevertheless, it is really annoying to be notified for junk email. Is there any way to stop this in Thunderbird without disabling sound notifications entirely?

I also have the same Hotmail account set up in the FairEmail client on Android, and I'm not getting false positive notifications there.

Answer (score 0):

A mitigation for this issue is to de-select "Allow immediate server notifications when new messages arrive" under Server Settings for the Hotmail account in Account Settings.

I also reduced the interval for "Check for new messages every _ minutes" to 2.

This way, new emails to the Inbox which are almost instantaneously moved to Junk by the Hotmail server do not trigger a false positive email notification in Thunderbird, while still allowing a pretty quick notification within 2 minutes.

This problem appears to be unique to Hotmail and seems to be a server side issue, not one with Thunderbird, but in any case this problem is solved with Thunderbird by effectively adding a delay to new email notifications.